# Return parent dictionary if key value exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If I have a file that contains these dictionaries:

```
bank = {
    "88386180860608512" : {
        "balance" : 100,
        "name" : "Aehnon"
    },
    "88469127777243136" : {
        "balance" : 100,
        "name" : "Balanceofevil"
    },
    "89741285950246912" : {
        "balance" : 3310,
        "name" : "Sharky"
    }
}
```

if this evaluates to True:

```
b  = [subdict["Name"] for subdict in bank.values()]
if "Sharky" in b:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

How can I print the dictionary it belongs to, 89741285950246912?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Iterate items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to get both `key` (89741285950246912) and `value`:

```
for account_no, account in bank.items():
    if account['name'] == 'Sharky':
        print(account_no)
```

prints:

```
89741285950246912
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehensions which returns a list of keys.

```
>>> bank = {
...     "88386180860608512" : {
...         "balance" : 100,
...         "name" : "Aehnon"
...     },
...     "88469127777243136" : {
...         "balance" : 100,
...         "name" : "Balanceofevil"
...     },
...     "89741285950246912" : {
...         "balance" : 3310,
...         "name" : "Sharky"
...     }
... }
>>> [key for key, value in bank.items() if value['name'] == 'Sharky']
['89741285950246912']
```